# Frequency response of common source amplifier and Millers theorem

Tags: analog, transfer-function, high-frequency

I was asked to draw the frequency response of a CS amplifier. The MOSFET has gate-drain capacitance between the input and output. This means that at high frequency, the output is shorted to input(the impedance of a capacitor decreases at high frequency). Which in turn says that there is a ZERO in the transfer function of the circuit.

But when I try it by using Millers theorem, the common capacitance between the input and output are resolved (see the pic). So there is no ZERO in the transfer function now.

[image]

So what does it mean? Whether the circuit has a zero or not?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are proving that it is a pole i.e. how it should be.

Comment: @Andyaka can you please be more clear?

Comment: I'm saying that the miller capacitor produces a pole and not a zero. What makes you suspect that a zero is produced?

Comment: Why don't you try to find out the transfer function in both the cases and check it yourself. They're bound to come out the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused because you are assuming that the circuit transformation which you made where you connected the \$C_{gd}\$ to an equivalent (bigger) capacitor to ground is valid at all frequencies. In fact, this transformation is valid only at low frequencies, below the bandwidth of the amplifier.
If you consider this equation at higher frequencies, then you also need to incorporate the fact that the gain itself is frequency dependent. Thus, the equivalent impedance comes to be \$\frac{1}{sC_{gd}(1+A(s))} \$. Clearly, the equivalent impedance is capacitive only at low frequencies and there is no equivalent lumped capacitor at higher frequencies. 
Since the frequency of zero is around \$\frac{g_m}{C_{gd}}\$ which is much beyond the bandwidth of the amplifier, your equivalent circuit is not applicable around that frequency region and will give you wrong conclusions. It's better to work with the original circuit in this region.

Answer (score 0):

circuit has hidden zero but certainly that zero is not due to miller capacitance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

General comment: The output is "shorted to the input" at infinite frequencies only. That means that at "very high" frequencies the input signal more and more goes directly to the ouput node via the drain-gate capacitance C. This is - indeed - identical to a zero in the transfer function.

Hence, the transfer function (gain) of a common source stage has both - a pole and a zero (drain resistor Rd, series input resistor Rs, drain-gate capacitance C, transconductance gm):

G(s)=(-gmRd + sRdC)/[1 + sC(Rd+Rs+gmRdRs)]

Note 1: The positive part in the numerator gives the portion of the output that is coupled directly to the output node via the capacitance C.

Note 2: The above gain formula G(s) assumes that the transconductance gm is constant. Hence, it does not contain te fact that gm decreases with frequency.

Note 3: Of course, the zero and the pole can be found by setting the numerator and the denominator equal to zero, respectively.

Note 4: The last most right part of the denominator expression contains the MILLER effect.