# What are limitations of Millers theorem for amplifier?

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, dual

I mean to say that are the two circuits one original and other its miller/ drawn exactly equal in all respects or their are some difference in some respect if so please mention.

I am not able to think about any other parameters except current hain voltage gain output impedance input impedance and frequency response which I think are same for both original and it's dual.I want to know any other parameters important for small signal analysis and also if those parameters are same for original and dual circuits.

I know that Millers dual is a bit of approximated because gain used to calculate dual impedance is calculated by neglecting the Impedance whose dual is been found.

It will also be helpful certain cases where this approximation actually produce lots of error.

Comment: I have left this question unedited so that you can see the effect that I mentioned. See above how "I know that Millers dual ..." is on the same line as "... please mention." BUT that in the actual text there is a line break between them. You have left ONE space after " ... mention." Add another space after " ... mention." and observe how thge output adss the intended line feed.

Comment: Thank you for editing!

Comment: Can you actually show a circuit example? I don't understand how "exactly equal" and "two different circuits" would even hypothetically work.

Comment: The two circuits are not equivalent in frequency response as you mentioned in your question...the original circuit has a zero which is not present in the simplified version.

Comment: I hope answer to this question helps: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/357783/frequency-response-of-common-source-amplifier-and-millers-theorem/424270#424270